# Footer in last printed page MPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Hi i am using MPDF but i cant print footer on the last page, i am printing 2-7 pages 
this is my code for footer

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
<div id="firmas">
<table width="100%"><tr>
<td><br><br><br><br><br><small><h3><font face=\'Arial\'>Recibí Conforme</font>
</h3><small>    </td><td><br><br><br><br><small><h3><font face=\'Arial    
\'>Vo.Bo</font>    
</h3><small></td><td><small><br><br><br><br><br><h3><font face=\'Arial\'>Entregue 
Conforme</font></h3><small></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
');
```

I would like to display this in the last page and not in every page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try first WriteHTML then SetHTMLFooter, order matters!

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div>your html footer</div>');
```

Comment: content gets overlapped by this method any workaround for that?